# Range of elements in a list

Tags: python-2.7, list, range

I'm new to programming, and I'm trying to solve this, how can I make a range for the elements in my list?

example:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
test = range(list[0], list[11])
print test
```

result:

```
[]
```

How to put the list elements from `0` to `11` in `test`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: range is used for generating a range of subsequent integers with a certain step between 2 numbers; if you need to pick elements from another array, you should use slicing instead, see the link by Azat

Comment: This is not reproducible, `test` isn't empty it is a populated list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you want to create a new list with elements 0 to 11 as integers, you can directly use the below method:

```
   test = range(0,12)
```

If you want to access data from existing list, you should use splice as shown below:

```
    test = list[0:12]
```